# The model is AlreadyRegistered at/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm getting an error:

```
AlreadyRegistered at / The model Post is already registered
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it? Here's my models.py :

```
from django.db import models from
django.contrib import admin


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Where have you put admin.autodiscover() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This generally happens when you register you models in models.py file which might be imported into some other modules. The recommended way is to create a separate admin.py file for registering your models.

Comment: I am getting this error and I don't why. I'm pretty sure I only registered the model once, and it was inside their respective admin.py, weeh strange!

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    body = models.TextField()   
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    search_fields = ["title"]

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```